# Macro escape string

Tags: escaping, sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to print a line to the console which should print one macro variable and one piece of text with an ampersand in it. Let me illustrate this with a small example:

```
%LET THIS_IS_A_MACRO_VAR = test; 
%PUT &THIS_IS_A_MACRO_VAR..&THIS_SHOULD_BE_TEXT;
```

When running this I would like the output to be:

```
test.&THIS_SHOULD_BE_TEXT
```

Coming from languages like PHP I expected there was something like an escape character. Unfortunately I could find anything similar.

I tried using different placements of ' and " but that led to both variable being interpreted as macro variable or both variables not. Also a try using %NRQUOTE was without succes. Lastly, I tried concatenating two strings: `"&THIS_IS_A_MACRO_VAR..&" || "THIS_SHOULD_BE_TEXT"`.

I hope someone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way is to simply separate the ampersand from the text, to prevent it being resolved as a macro variable, as follows:

```
%LET THIS_IS_A_MACRO_VAR = test; 
%PUT &THIS_IS_A_MACRO_VAR..%str(&)THIS_SHOULD_BE_TEXT;
```

this gives:

```
test.&THIS_SHOULD_BE_TEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the usual way to do this would be to escape the entire bit of text with non-resolution escaping.  SAS certainly has very powerful (but very confusing) escaping options.

```
%nrstr(&this_should_be_text)
```

That would be the simplest, if it's only attempted to be resolved once.  You might need to use `bquote` or similar if it needs to stay escaped for several resolution passes.  See [Secrets of Macro Quoting Functions](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi28/011-28.pdf) by Susan O'Connor for more details.